# CrossTabManagerError appears in creating changes map while using MOLUSCE Plugin in QGIS

Tags: qgis-plugins, qgis-processing, error, qgis-2

I'm using QGIS 2.16.0 Wein and the Plugin MOLUSCE(ver. 3. 0. 13). Now I'm trying to create a change map, but get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "C:/Users/DENR/.qgis2/python/plugins\molusce\moluscedialog.py", line 422, in startUpdateStatisticsTable
                crossTabMan = CrossTableManager(self.inputs["initial"], self.inputs["final"])
              File "C:/Users/DENR/.qgis2/python/plugins\molusce\algorithms\models\crosstabs\manager.py", line 33, in __init__
                raise CrossTabManagerError("An input raster has more then one band. Use 1-band rasters!")
            CrossTabManagerError
```

What to do?

Comment: What is your input raster? Can you please describe it?